PDF conditional form fields not updating appearances in pdf-lib despite setting values programmatically
I'm working on a project where I need to programmatically fill out and save PDF forms using pdf-lib. I've encountered an issue specifically with conditional form fields—such as radio buttons and text fields—that are not updating their appearances in the PDF viewer despite setting values programmatically.
The issue occurs specifically with conditional fields—when certain radio buttons or checkboxes need to show or hide associated input fields based on user selections. Despite setting values programmatically and calling updateFieldAppearances(), the PDF viewer does not consistently update the appearances of these conditional fields until I manually interact with the checkboxes.
This issue happens only when i open the filled pdf on Chrome browser or fire fox. It works on adobe reader and few other PDF viewers. But i need to make it usable in any kind of viwer.
Is there a specific approach or additional step I should take to ensure that PDF conditional form field appearances are updated correctly without manual interaction?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Code Sandbox link: Sandbox
This is a sample of what i have already tried.
const updatePdfForm = async () => {
  try {
    const pdfPath = window.location.origin + "/test.pdf"; // Correctly reference the PDF file
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(pdfPath).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

    form.acroForm.dict.set(PDFName.of("NeedAppearances"), PDFBool.True);

    // Update radio button 
    const radio = form.getRadioGroup("2.0");
    const radioOptions = radio.getOptions();
    radio.select(radioOptions[0]);
    radio.defaultUpdateAppearances(); // Update appearance explicitly

    // Update text fields (example)
    const textField1 = form.getTextField("2.date02.d_F");
    textField1.setText("12");
    const textField2 = form.getTextField("2.date02.m_F");
    textField2.setText("12");
    const textField3 = form.getTextField("2.date02.y_F");
    textField3.setText("2024");

    // Save PDF with updated appearances
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save({ updateFieldAppearances: true });
    const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: "application/pdf" });
    saveAs(blob, "filled_template.pdf"); // Save the PDF file as 'filled_template.pdf'
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating PDF:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

updatePdfForm();

